# How to bind with a static property

Tags: asp.net, binding

I want to bind with a static property in my application, is that possible?

I've tried this:

```
<asp:ListItem Enabled="<%$ MyNamespace:myClassName, MyBooleanPropertyName  %>">
```

And the following message is appeared:

> Parser Error Message: The expression prefix 'MyNamespace' was not recognized.  Please correct the prefix or register the prefix in the  section of configuration.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following format to bind to a `static` property:

```
Property="<%# MyNamespace.myClassName.MyBooleanPropertyName  %>"
```